# jQuery resizing images upon initial load of webpage

Tags: jquery, resize, margins

Ok, Looking at this page in Google Chrome here on a MAC OSX:  http://opportunityfinance.net/Test/2013conf/index.html

Scrolling down to see the following:

[image: Initial Loading issue in Chrome]

If you resize the browser window, it than aligns correctly as in the following picture below:

[image: What it Should Look Like and how it looks when resizing the browser window]

So, my question is how can I get the appearance in the 2nd pic upon initial loading of the page?  Google Chrome initially sets the height of the `<div class="gold">` to 0px with the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var gold = $(".gold");

    $(window).bind("resize", function(){
        gold.css({'height': gold.children(":first").children("img").height()});             
    }).trigger("resize");
});
```

Here is the HTML that I'm using:

```
<div class="gold" style="width: 100%; position: relative; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em;">
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; width: 32%;">
        <img src="images/wellsfargo.png" alt="Wells Fargo" style="border: none; max-width: 100%;">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 32%; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute;">
        <img src="images/citi.png" alt="Citi" style="max-width: 100%; border: none;">
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 34%; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;">
        <img src="images/gs10ksb.png" alt="Goldman Sachs 10000 Small Businesses" style="border: none; max-width: 100%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: personally, I like to stay away from absolute positioning if possible, and this is one example of something you can do without absolute.

Comment: How so?  Not sure if this is possible for the same look...

Comment: for elements listed on top of eachother (platinum, bank of america..), use `display:block`.
for elements listed next to eachother (citi, goldman sachs..), use `display:inline-block`.

Comment: `display: inline-block` not supported in IE 7 and/or 8

Comment: I believe I solved this problem.  Removed `position: absolute` and added: `float: right` to the first div.  Seems to have worked, and no height settings need to be made to the `<div>` either, when doing this way.  Thanks a lot!  `position: absolute;` was definitely the culprit.  I'm hoping that it looks good in all browsers now.

Comment: Thanks a million Justin Gingy McDonald!

Comment: No problem, although I have found that the best solutions (for cross browser support & resizing) strive to avoid absolute as well as floats. Just a heads up, they are tricky attributes!